# how to implement bulk trigger for this code

Tags: apex

```
if(trigger.IsInsert){
  List<Accountone__c> accone = new List<Accountone__c>();
  for(Account a2:Trigger.new)
  {
   Accountone__c c1 = new Accountone__c();
      c1.Name = a2.Name;
      c1.Phone__c = a2.phone;
      accone.add(c1);
  }
  insert accone;
 }
```

i have some doubt how to implement for bulk trigger above this code ,
can tell any suggestion for this code

Thanks,
Ganesh

Comment: This looks bulkified to me

Comment: but processing will same , how to update for this code can u tell me

Comment: The trigger is bulkified - that is the dml operation is outside the for loop meaning that it can handle several hundred records at once without hitting governer limits. No need to change anything.

Answer (score 5):

Your trigger is already bulkified - meaning that it will scale to handle 1 - 200 records in a single call.

In your particular case, the only area of concern would be the insertion of the newly created AccountOne__c records.  As you have stored the records in a list and then inserted all records in the list once you have finished iterating the trigger records, you will only consume a single DML operation out of the limit of 150 (as of Summer 13).